# Represent spiral of numbers in a matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

How to dynamically fill the following output in a two-dimensional array with the same number of rows and columns.

[image]

**Edit:** Here is the solution in c++ using @TheGeneral code from c#.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int size = 10;
    int half = size/2;
    int matrix[size][size];
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i<=size; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<= size; j++){
            if(i > half){
                number1 = size + 1 - i;
            }else{
                number1 = i;
            }
            if(j > half){
                number2 = size + 1 - j;
            }else{
                number2 = j;
            }
            if(number1 < number2){
                matrix[i-1][j-1] = number1;
            }else{
                matrix[i-1][j-1] = number2;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"MATRIX:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            cout<<"["<<matrix[i][j]<<"] \t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bit of fun

The only note worthy things going on, are

- Starting the index from 1 (makes things easier)
- [Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to say if an index is greater than `5` reverse the count
- [Math.Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it syemtrical

**Exmaple**

```
private static int[, ] CreateArray()
{
    var ary = new int[10, 10];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            ary[i - 1, j - 1] = Math.Min(i > 5 ? 11 - i : i, j > 5 ? 11 - j : j);
    return ary;
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7uhZqc)

Comment: @joepa37 no problems